# <a> tag fills up entire page width?

Tags: html, css

Here's some very simple HTML

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.box img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 425px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="box-a">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="movies.jpg">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

But, for some reason, when I run this code, the <a> tag fills up the entire width of the page. Does anyone know why this is, and how i could prevent it in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<a>` is by default an inline element, since the div is a `display: block` element it will fill the entire page.

You have two ways to go from here:

- You can change it to `display: inline-block` and your link will fill only on your box;
- Or you can set a `max-width` to you `<a>` and set it as a `display: block`

```css
a.box-a{
    display: inline-block
}

a.box-b{
    max-width: 300px;
    display: block;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.box img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 425px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="box-a">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="movies.jpg">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#" class="box-b">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="movies.jpg">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Just check on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block) if the `display: inline-block` compatibility matches your project criteria, if not then go by the `display: block; max-width: 300px` solution.

Comment: display: inline-block worked great! Thanks. Will accept asap

Comment: we can also add inline-flex to anchor if you want to use flex.

a.box-a{
    display: inline-flex;
}